# How do I get images named sequentially when using the 'Frame step' render option?

Tags: rendering

I skipped frames using the Frame Step Control in the Dimensions panel of the Render tab to output the sequence.

As a result, if you look at the names of the files in the Windows folder, you can see that there are omissions in number increments like img_1, img_3, img_5 ....

I'm currently converting names manually using a separate name batch tool, but this is a cumbersome and repetitive task.

Is there a way to have a sequential number, even if I output a skipped frame using the Frame Step function in Blender?

---

Thank you for suggesting great methods.

Your method works great on single-pass output.

But there is one thing I have not told you.

**I actually want to use multi-pass output using the file output node.**

I have found the Time Remapping feature in the dimension panel of the Render tab in other threads, but this causes distortion in the keyframe and interframe spacing.

The way to use the Speed Control Strip in VSE was not distorted, but it could not be used with the file output node. (It seems to be the best way for a single pass.)

The Windows automatic name feature is nice. Thanks Bill Gates, but it is still inconvenient to work with many passes and cuts.

And I'm going to try another batch name tool I did not know about.
I hope I can change the odd number to a sequential number with one click.
But I have not tried it yet.

Is there any other way to get sequential numbering of images output through **the Frame Step option and the file output node?**

---

I attached a screenshot at the request of Mutant Bob.

As you can see, I would like to use the file-out node to output multiple passes on one Scene and send it to another composite tool (Natron, Fusion, Nuke, AE, 
 Reimport to Blender, etc ...) With the Frame Step option in the Dimensions Panel, fill in the Value Box with two or more numbers. (I'm creating CG for inserting into 12fps 2D animation.)

VSE could not be used with the File Output node because only a single input connected to a Composite node could be loaded into a Strip.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link that describes "multi pass output using the file output node".  I want to figure out if there's a way to make it work in a normal rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two techniques:

1) Create a second scene using the VSE to add a Scene strip and then apply a Speed Control modifier to make the scene run double speed.

2) use a shell script to make symlinks like

```
i=1

S=/var/tmp/blender/knot-hop

D=$S/sequence

mkdir $D

for f in $S/scene1/*.png $S/scene2/*.png $S/scene3/*.png; do
    o=$D/$(printf %04d $i).png
    [ -e $o ] && rm $o
    ln -s $f $o
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done

# make sure we don't have any stale files left over
o=$D/$(printf %04d $i).png
rm -f $o
```

Comment: Wow.  That file node stack you added to the question is pretty tall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows and all images are in the same folder, you can do this:

**1. Select the first file**

[image]

**2. Select all by CTRL-A**

[image]

**3. Press F2 and type a new name**

[image]

**4. Call Bill Gates to say "Thank you"**

Drawbacks:

1. It's not fully automated
2. The postfix is always in brackets like (1), (2) etc.

Comment: For the drawback №2 one should really thank Bill Gates. And likely use external file manager

Comment: There are many bulk rename apps that you can use for free, I use [ReName](https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer). For Mac [R-name](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12259/r-name) and [métamorphose2](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/) Linux/Mac/Windows... No thanks from me to Mr Gates or  Mr. Jobs